# Failed to execute a migrated DTS 2000 package in SSIS 2008 with TLS1.2 enabled OS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, tls1.2, ssis-2008, dts

I have a SSIS package which was migrated from DTS 2000 to SSIS 2008.

The package designed to perform following jobs:

1. Perform the data cleansing by truncate the tables in SQL Server
2. Transform data from Oracle Database into SQL Server tables (this task is bind into a package called "DTS 2000 Package Task")

The package is working fine until the server (Windows Server 2008 R2) which install SQL Server 2008 enabled TLS1.2 and disabled TLS1.0 & TLS1.1

**Error thrown by DTEXEC:**

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040427): Execution was cancelled by user." thrown when executing task #2 (Oracle to SQL server data transformation). Data cleansing part was done successfully.

**Error found in event viewer:**

> A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.

I have tried following

1. Patch Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL server 2008 R2 to the latest version
2. Tried difference Oracle DB providers: OLEDB (Oracle Provider for OLE DB), MSDAORA (Microsoft OLE DB provider for Oracle), ODBC
3. Installed latest Microsoft OLE DB provider for SQL Server - Microsoft® OLE DB Driver 18 for SQL Server®

I suspected the problem is due to "DTS 2000 Package Task" try to use TLS1.0 protocol when executing the task.

Any idea how can i force the DTS use TLS1.2?

Any help will greatly appreciated.